# Groovy - String to Time

Tags: java, string, time, groovy, type-conversion

I have a String like this:

```
String timeString = "2230"
```

And I want to convert it into Time type.

I have tried to use this

```
def bookingTime = new Date().parse("2230")
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Try (Groovy implementation):

```
String timeString = "2230"
def bookingTime = Date.parse("HHmm", timeString)
```

Comment: I tried it but still doesn't work. It throws me an exception like this: "Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: {"HHmm", "1100"}"

Comment: Almost impossible, this method is in groovy from v. 1.5.7. Please edit Your question and provide full (not)working example.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Groovy well, but I assume it does not have its own libraries, at least for date-time work. So this answer is aimed at Java libraries.

## Date-Time versus Time-Of-Day

> I want to convert it into Time type.

Apparently you want to represent only a time-of-day without any date or time zone.

The java.util.Date/.Calendar classes bundled with Java represent a combination of date and time-of-day. (By the way, these classes are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them.)

So, Java 7 and earlier has no "Time" type. Java has had a [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html), but this class is a hack. A .Time is a j.u.Date with its date portion set to first day of 1970 UTC (the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date))). This class is only intended for use with databases and JDBC, and even then is supplanted by java.time (see below).

Instead you should use either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library
- [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package (built into Java 8, inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310)

Both of these libraries offer a `LocalTime` class ([Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html), [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)) to represent a time-only value without date and without time zone.

### Joda-Time

Some example code in Joda-Time 2.5, using Java syntax rather than Groovy.

If your input string had colons it would follow standard ISO 8601 format. The standard formats are used in both Joda-Time and java.time by default for parsing and generating strings.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( "18:55" );  // ISO 8601 format used by default.
System.out.println( "localTime: " + localTime );  // localTime: 18:55:00.000
```

With your non-standard format, you must specify a formatter.

```
LocalTime localTime2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "HHmm" ).parseLocalTime( "2230" );
System.out.println( "localTime2: " + localTime2 );  // localTime2: 22:30:00.000
```